# How do i store the text of a button in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, function, button, global-variables, addeventlistener

I am trying to store the text of a button in a variable or function that i can use later. So it should be in the global scope i suppose. But i can't figure out how to do that because if I console.log the function it shows *undefined*. I'm supposing it's because the main function doesn't actually return anything, the nested one does. I was thinking about giving names to the nested functions but i can't figure out how to name these forEach and eventListener functions or if that would even help me. I am so lost. Please send help

```js
function choice() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let playerChoice = event.target.textContent;
      return playerChoice;
    });
  });
}
console.log(choice());
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="rock">rock</button>
  <button class="paper">paper</button>
  <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
</div>
```

If instead i console.log the playerChoice and then i call the function it works but from what i know i can't store that result.

Comment: The return value of the event listener isn't used for anything. Remember, the event listener runs when the user clicks, which will be long after you call `choice()`. `choice()` doesn't wait for the click.

Comment: Thanks! So what should i do?

Comment: Depends on what you want to use the text variable for, and in particular, when and how often (on every click? on some other event?)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a global variable. But it won't be available to log until after the user clicks, so you need another event listener to show that.

```js
let playerChoice;

function choice() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      playerChoice = event.target.textContent;
    });
  });
}

choice();
document.querySelector("#show").addEventListener('click', () => console.log(playerChoice));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="rock">rock</button>
  <button class="paper">paper</button>
  <button class="scissors">scissors</button>
</div>

<button id="show">What did I click?</button>
```

Comment: You only have one container class. Wouldn't `document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener` be better?

Comment: I was wondering about that myself. But since it's not relevant to the issue I left it alone. I suspect the OP may have intended `document.querySelectorAll('.container button')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it in global variable, then declare the variable and set the value while you are clicking it. I have also gave you another function, `getPlayerChoice` as optional if you want to call any function to do certain things you can do in that way -

```
var playerChoice;

function getPlayerChoice(text) {
    console.log("text", text);
    console.log("global value", playerChoice);
    // You can do your work here
}

function choice() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.container').forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            playerChoice = event.target.textContent;
            getPlayerChoice(playerChoice);
        });
    });
}
```